# Mouse event not being triggered on html5 canvas

Tags: javascript, html, html5-canvas, dom-events

I would like to know if there is any special way that one would use to register events for html5 canvas elements?

The following code won't raise any mouse events on my canvas elements:

```
function MyObject() {
   this.init();
};

MyObject.prototype.init = function() {
   var canvas = document.getElementById('myCanvas');
   var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
   var anImage = new Image('image1.png');

   ctx.drawImage(anImage, 0, 0, 100, 100, 0, 0, 100, 100);

   canvas.onmousedown = createDelegate(this, this.mouseDownEvent);
}

MyObject.prototype.mouseDownEvent = function(e) {
    //Not even reaching this point.
}

var obj = new MyObject();
```

the **mouseDownEvent** function is not even getting called when I click on the canvas. Can anybody tell me whats wrong with the code.

**N.B. Swapping out the canvas for image tags fixes the problem.**

Comment: I don't know html structure of your document, but the most possible reason is that canvas is overlapped by some other element with higher z-index. canvas.onmousedown definitely works, I used it.

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code, the source of your problems must lie elsewhere. See: http://jsfiddle.net/9FPAB/

Comment: Ok, I know this is strange but by adding a -webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0) styling to the canvas element seems to have fixed the issue...weird.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Ok, I know this is strange but by adding a

```
-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0)
```

styling to the canvas element seems to have fixed the issue...weird.

Answer (score 1):

This is a little late, but I just had a similar experience. I detailed it here: [Putting HTML5 <canvas> inside <table> nullifies mouse events](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42899889/putting-html5-canvas-inside-table-nullifies-mouse-events/42916703). It turns out that the mouse events were still triggering, but all my calculated coordinates were way off due to be calculating relative to the wrong offset.

This is probably too late to help you, but maybe it'll satisfy your intellectual curiosity?