# Putting HTML5 <canvas> inside <table> nullifies mouse events

Tags: javascript, css, html, html5-canvas

I have an HTML5 canvas object, that uses the `addEventListener()` method multiple times, to be able to respond to mouse events. The lines I use looks like this:

`canvas.addEventListener("mousemove", this.checkMouseLocation.bind(this, this.inputs), false);`

This all works perfectly well, so long as the canvas is directly inside the document's body, or in a div. However, it doesn't work inside a table. Once the canvas is placed there, all the mouse events appear to stop firing.

After reading [Mouse event not being triggered on html5 canvas](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8986972/mouse-event-not-being-triggered-on-html5-canvas), I decided to try that solution--to add the property `style="-webkit-transform: translate3d(0, 0, 0);"` to my canvas. This fixed the issue in Firefox, but in Chrome it still refuses to pay attention to the mouse.

Does anybody have any ideas? Best guess is that this has something to do with mouse coordinates, though I couldn't tell you how.

Thanks.

Comment: Out of curiosity: why do you have a `<canvas>` element inside a `<table>`? The table element is used to represent tabular data, and I'm imagining there are not very many situations where a canvas element would count as tabular data.

Comment: The canvas is being used for an animation--in this case, logic gates (and, or, etc.). Since there are multiple ones, I wanted to show them all side by side.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the answer, for any who come after me.

The mouse messages weren't totally nixed--they were still happening. However, the mouse's x and y coordinates were totally off, to the point where it wasn't responding to them.

I had been calculating my mouse's coordinates by subtracting the canvas's offset from the mouse's location, like this:

```
var x = event.pageX - canvas.offsetLeft;
var y = event.pageY - canvas.offsetTop;
```

Unfortunately, this isn't dependable, because the `canvas` object's offsets aren't always with respect to the document body. When inside a table, they were relative to the `<td>` the `canvas` is inside. So the coordinates were way off, making the `canvas` object appear to be totally nonresponsive to the mouse.

I replaced those lines with these:

```
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var x = event.clientX - rect.left;
var y = event.clientY - rect.top;
```

This seems a little kludgey, since the gods only know how efficient the `getBoundingClientRect()` function is, and it means that I'm dealing with floating-point coordinates rather than integer coordinates. But the x and y I calculate are accurate, and that's more important.

I hope that this helps someone else down the road.

Comment: performance wise, gBCR should be about exactly the same as `.offsetLeft` and `.offsetTop`, even if the laters look like fixed properties, they are actually recalculated the same exact way gBCR. (of course there may be some minimal differences, since it is creating a DOMRect, but nothing to worry about if you're not calling it 10 thousands times in a loop.

Comment: Thanks @Kaiido. Do you happen to have a good source of info on how to determine if a JavaScript program is efficient or not? Aside from basic programming practices (e.g. complexity analysis), this has always eluded me.